# GCP service account access issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a json file with service account credentials and used it like below in a `cloud-sdk:357.0.0-alpine` sidecar container.

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=credentials.json`

`gsutil ls gs://foo/bar/baz`

Since `cloud-sdk:alpine` container is around 600 MB I decided to use rclone container ~ 50MB and used below command to do `ls`

`rclone config create gcs_remote gcs --gcs-service-account-file credentials.json`

`rclone ls gcs_remote:foo/bar/baz`

But this is failing with error `Failed to ls: googleapi: Error 403: foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket., forbidden`

Comment: what roles did you give to the service account that you created the credentials.json file from?

Comment: I don't have permissions to check this but my question is if the same service-account can access bucket content with `gcloud auth` and `gsutil ls` commands why can't it access through `rclone ls`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this issue - I found `rclone config` was not picking service-account file and that's the reason for `Error 403`.

I passed it with `RCLONE_CONFIG_GCS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` env variable and it worked!